# Create a Team Project with TFS SDK from C# .Net App

Tags: c#, .net, rest, tfs, team-project

I want to create a new Team Project with the TFS SDK (namespace Microsoft.TeamFoundation;). But I haven't found anything appropriate so far.

I searched the Internet and only saw that I could use the official REST API for TFS: https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/tfs/projects (See at "Create a team project")

What's the best way to create a Team Project using C# .Net?

Thanks for any advice given.

Answer (score 2):

Write C# code that invokes the REST API. There may also be something in the new REST API wrappers that you can get from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/14.95.3)

The old-style TFS SOAP API cannot create Team Projects as far as I know.

Comment: Note that the REST API to create a Team Project is available on VSTS or TFS 2015 with Update 2 or later.